# Permission denied when running C program

Tags: c

I am trying to run this basic file (ex1.c) with zsh

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("hello world.");

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
zsh: permission denied: ./ex1.c
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to compile it first, probably by doing `gcc -o ex1 ex1.c`.
After compiling it, you will have an executable called `ex1`, which you can run by doing `./ex1`.
If you receive another `permission denied` error, you can make it executable by doing `chmod +x ex1`.

Comment: Normally compilers are smart enough to set the executable bit by themselves.

Comment: jeez i'm an idiot, I compiled but was running ex1.c not ex1, thanks!

Comment: I just needed to do a fresh build and then it ran fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just run a file with C code. You'll have to first compile it. If you have a `gcc` compiler available, that's going to be:

```
gcc -o ex1 ex.c
./ex1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a C source file, it is not supposed to be run like this, you have to compile it first.

This would do:

```
make ex1 # Implicit rule which in turn will perform cc -o ex1 ex1.c
./ex1
```

Comment: Entirely incorrect if he doesn't have a makefile.

Comment: It's implicit rule. Try it.

Comment: Maybe your system makes it implicit, but mine doesn't.  However, http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html does say it's a rule, so I will agree with it.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules - "linking a single object file"